# Can I edit table in powpoint by office-js now?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I want to reshape all selected items in PowerPoint by `office-js`.

But all the table's `shape.type` are `"Unsupported"` and the code below can not change the table width.

```js
async function resizeSelectedShapes() {
  await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
    // First, get the current selection
    const selection = context.presentation.getSelectedShapes();
    selection.load("items");
    const shapeCounts = selection.getCount();
    await context.sync();

    selection.items.map((shape) => {
      shape.load("left,right,width,height");
    });
    await context.sync();
    const rsize = 0.8;
    selection.items.map((shape) => {
      shape.left *= 0.8;
      console.log(shape.type);
      shape.width *= 0.8;
      if (shape.type == "Image") {
        shape.height *= 0.8;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I found I can use table in powerpoint web version, so access table in PowerPoint in `office-js` is possible or not？

Answer (score 0):

The supported list of shapes are defined in the [PowerPoint.ShapeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.shapetype?view=powerpoint-js-preview) enum. As you can see, there is no table in the list of supported shapes. So, you may post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.

You may find the [Work with shapes using the PowerPoint JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/powerpoint/shapes) page helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I have read these page, none of these mentioned `table`, even not in a "not suported list". So I asked this question to make sure if I missed something.

Comment: You may post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.